# How to reload an angular constructor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have my "account" component that depending if the user is logged in shows different html content. If the user is logged in the page shows the profile info, if not it shows an log in form.
The thing is that, if you're not logged and you sign in, the page content changes to the "profile view", but any of the user data that the constructor gets from backend doesn't appear on screen unless you reload the page, it's there any way to change this?

I leave some part of the code

AccountComponent

```
user:any

  constructor(public auth: AuthService, private router: Router, private alert: Ion_Alert) {
    if(this.auth.isLoggedIn){
      this.user = this.auth.getUserData().subscribe({
        next: ( data:any ) => {
          this.user = data.data.person
          console.log(this.user)
        },
        error: error => {
          this.alert.showAlert("Error!", error.message)
          console.error('There was an error!', error)
        }
      })
    } else {
      this.alert.showAlert('Error!', "You're not logged in or you haven't verified your mail")
    }
  }
```

Account HTML

```
<ion-content>
  <div *ngIf="this.auth.isLoggedIn">
      <h1 *ngIf="user.first_name">{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</h1>
          <h1 *ngIf="user.business_name">{{user.business_name}}</h1>
          <h3 *ngIf="user.documents_type.id === 1">DNI: {{user.dni}}</h3>
          <h3 *ngIf="user.documents_type.id === 2">NIT: {{user.nit}}</h3>
  </div>
  
  <app-sign-in *ngIf="!this.auth.isLoggedIn"></app-sign-in>
</ion-content>
```

Sign-in HTML

```
<ion-content>
    //Ionic sign in form
<ion-row>
          <ion-col>
            <ion-button type="submit" color="light" expand="block" (click)="this.auth.signIn(userEmail.value, userPassword.value)">Sign In</ion-button>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col>
            <ion-button routerLink="/register" color="primary" expand="block">Sign Up</ion-button>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

Auth Service stuff

```
getUserData() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.env.API_URL}/users/firebase/${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).uid}`)
  }

signIn(email, password) {
    return this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          if(this.welcome_message === false) {this.alert.showAlert("Welcome!", "Nice to see u' again!")}
          this.router.navigate(['/tabs/home'])
        });
        this.setUserData(result.user);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.dir(error)
        this.alert.showAlert("Error!", error.message)
      })
  }
```

Comment: You probably want to move the call to the backend out of the constructor and into its own function. Then, in your auth service have an observable that you subscribe to. Fire the observable when the auth state changes and make your calls to the backend.

Comment: The thing is that i can only subscribe when the service is called, in this case when the account component is loaded. There's any way i could trigger a ngonchange on the <app-sign-in> to call the backend?

Comment: You could try running the changeDetector from your auth service. Doesn't seem like the greatest solution though.

Comment: you have to use `Ionic Life Cycle` events